# Send report with Crashlytics Android SDK

Tags: android, crashlytics

In **Crashlytics** support database there [is information](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/187437-how-do-i-localize-the-send-crash-reports-dialog-on) about how to localize Send Report dialog.
But I can't find how to open such dialog to allow the user to send a report.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at their [KB article about that](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/349914-can-i-toggle-whether-or-not-a-user-needs-to-give-p)

You go into an app and click "Enable Privacy Prompt" and choose "Ask Users" in the dialog box, whenever the app crashes a box should appear asking to send the report.